# Is a url query parameter valid if it has no value?

Tags: url, query-string

Is a url like `http://example.com/foo?bar` valid?

I'm looking for a link to something official that says one way or the other.  A simple yes/no answer or anecdotal evidence won't cut it.

Comment: In addition to the URI RFC I want to point out a real world example of this. Drupal uses these valueless query parameters in some links as a form of cache busting. e.g. www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js?o490ub or /themes/seven/ie.css?o4eppb.  You probably already know this but some stumbling upon this might not.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

- Valid to the URI RFC
- Likely acceptable to your server-side framework/code

The [URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) doesn't mandate a format for the query string.  Although it is recognized that the query string will often carry name-value pairs, it is not required to (e.g. it will often contain another URI).

> 3.4.  Query
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
> data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
> resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
> (if any).  ...
>
> ... However, as query components
> are often used to carry identifying information in the form of
> "key=value" pairs and one frequently used value is a reference to
> another URI, ...

[HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) establishes that a form submitted via HTTP GET should encode the form values as name-value pairs in the form "?key1=value1&key2=value2..." (properly encoded).  Parsing of the query string is up to the server-side code (e.g. Java servlet engine).

You don't identify what server-side framework you use, if any, but it is possible that your server-side framework may assume the query string will always be in name-value pairs and it may choke on a query string that is not in that format (e.g. `?bar`).  If its your own custom code parsing the query string, you simply have to ensure you handle that query string format.  If its a framework, you'll need to consult your documentation or simply test it to see how it is handled.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC (versions 4 and 5 to my knowledge) definitely choke when there is no value provided :(

Comment: The `isindex` magic `name` from HTML5 allows sending a query string without key-value format http://stackoverflow.com/a/37579004/895245

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 as a [deprecated feature for legacy support of HTML3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41689431/124486)

Answer (score 151):

They're perfectly valid. You could consider them to be the equivalent of the big muscled guy standing silently behind the mob messenger. The guy doesn't have a name and doesn't speak, but his mere presence conveys information.

Comment: The mobster's muscled guy has a name, you just don't know it. You know it on the param though and it basically carries a boolean value (present, absent).

Comment: The best way to describe it :)

Comment: The big guy's name is *Cheich*, from that casino heist episode on Star Trek: Deep Space 9.

Comment: Well, he has a name - it's the name of the parameter :D

Answer (score 13):

"The "http" scheme is used to locate network resources via the HTTP protocol. This section defines the scheme-specific syntax and semantics for http URLs." http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

```
http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
```

So yes, anything is valid after a question mark. Your server may interpret differently, but **anecdotally**, you can see some languages treat that as a boolean value which is true if listed.

Comment: For the formal definition, see RFC 2396 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), which is silent on the contents of the query string, other than to specify the legal set of characters, and those that have special meaning. Specifically, it says that the "query component is a string of information to be interpreted by
the resource," implying that its definition is dependent on the protocol, and thus the _key=value_ is largely by convention.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is valid.

If one simply want to check if the parameter exists or not, this is one way to do so.

Answer (score 6):

## URI Spec

The only relevant part of the URI spec is to know *everything* between the first `?` and the first `#` fits the spec's definition of a query. It can include any characters such as `[:/.?]`. This means that a query string such as `?bar`, or `?ten+green+apples` is valid.

Find the [RFC 3986 here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

## HTML Spec

`isindex` is not meaningfully HTML5.

It's provided **deprecated** for use as the first element in a form only, and submits without a name.

> If the entry's name is "isindex", its type is "text", and this is the first entry in the form data set, then append the value to result and skip the rest of the substeps for this entry, moving on to the next entry, if any, or the next step in the overall algorithm otherwise.
>
> The isindex flag is for legacy use only. Forms in conforming HTML documents will not generate payloads that need to be decoded with this flag set.

The last time [isindex was supported was HTML3](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#isindex). It's use in HTML5 is to provide easier backwards compatibility.

## Support in libraries

Support in libraries for this format of URI varies however some libraries do provide legacy support to ease use of `isindex`.

### Perl [URI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) (special support)

Some libraries like [Perl's URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) provide methods of parsing these kind of structures

```
$uri->query_keywords
$uri->query_keywords( $keywords, ... )
$uri->query_keywords( \@keywords )
Sets and returns query components that use the keywords separated by "+" format.
```

### Node.js [`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_urlobject_query) (no special support)

As another far more frequent example, `node.js` takes the normal route and eases parsing as either

- A string
- or, an object of keys and values (using `parseQueryString`)

Most other URI-parsing APIs following something similar to this.

- PHP [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), follows as similar implementation but only returns the string for the query. [Parsing into an object of `k=>v` requires `parse_string()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5397726/124486)

Answer (score 3):

It is valid: see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure), [RFC 1738 (3.3. HTTP)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html), [RFC 3986 (3.  Syntax Components)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).

Comment: Note that RFC 2396 "revises and replaces the generic definitions in RFC 1738 and RFC 1808."

Answer (score 3):

**`isindex` deprecated magic `name` from HTML5**

This deprecated feature allows a form submission to generate such an URL, providing further evidence that it is valid for HTML. E.g.:

```
<form action="#isindex" class="border" id="isindex" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="isindex" value="bar"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

generates an URL of type:

```
?bar
```

Standard: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute

`isindex` is however deprecated as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41689431/895245

Answer (score 1):

As all other answers described, it's perfectly valid for checking, specially for boolean kind stuff

Here is a simple function to get the query string by name:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
        url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and now you want to check if the query string you are looking for exists or not, you may do a simple thing like:

```
var exampleQueryString = (getParameterByName('exampleQueryString') != null);
```

the `exampleQueryString` will be `false` if the function can't find the query string, otherwise will be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct resource to look for this is [RFC6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570). Please refer to section 3.2.9 where in examples empty parameter is presented as below.

```
 Example Template     Expansion
   {&x,y,empty}       &x=1024&y=768&empty=
```