# Parse query string into an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I turn a **string** below into an **array**?

```
pg_id=2&parent_id=2&document&video
```

This is the array I am looking for,

```
array(
    'pg_id' => 2,
    'parent_id' => 2,
    'document' => ,
    'video' =>
)
```

Comment: The documentation for [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) does not explain it well. [This is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792310/parse-str-need-someting-on-php7/53792394#53792394) (my emphasis): *"Without the second argument to parse_str(), the query string parameters would* ***populate the local symbol table***. *Given the security implications of this, using parse_str() without a second argument has now been deprecated."*

Answer (score 394, accepted):

You want the [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function, and you need to set the second parameter to have the data put in an array instead of into individual variables.

```php
$queryString = "pg_id=2&parent_id=2&document&video";
 
parse_str($queryString, $queryArray);

print_r($queryArray);
```

Comment: I have a problem with this answer, because it does not work if you use the same key multiple times (yes because in php array keys are unique). So `?key=lorem&key=ipsum` will result in `array(["key"]=>"ipsum")` The question is, is there a function to get s.th. like this `array(["key"]=>array("lorem", "ipsum"))` or do I have to create this function on my own?

Comment: Technically PHP would also treat `?key=lorem&key=ipsum` as if you only provided `key=ipsum` if that were the query string on the URL. And I think it's considered invalid to reuse the key and expect consistent results or that all instances of the key are retained. The valid approach, at least for a query string sent to PHP, would be `?key[]=lorem&key[]=ipsum`, so your homegrown approach might look for any occurrences of  `&{x}=` where x occurs more than once and replace with `x[]` (and treating ? as same as &)

Comment: @Mabi - oh, and look, someone else agrees with you and created their own function already - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#76792

Comment: That was helpfull! I deciceded to do it like this `?key[]=lorem&key[]=ipsum` some weeks ago. But thanks for sharing the link!

Comment: Something to watch out for are strings that include '+', like myemail+alias@gmail.com. These will be parsed by parse_str to a space. key=myemail alias@gmail.com.

Comment: @dudeman, this is because the symbol `+` is a deprecated, but still supported and extendedly use for spaces. But this can easily fix by replacing `+` for it's encoded value `%2B`. For more info about the spaces encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20

Comment: @Anthony the answer at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#76792 is very incomplete and (doesn't apply urldecode to the key/values and falls over if there's no equals sign with a key).

Answer (score 76):

Sometimes `parse_str()` alone is note accurate, it could display for example:

```
$url = "somepage?id=123&lang=gr&size=300";
```

parse_str() would return:

```
Array ( 
    [somepage?id] => 123 
    [lang] => gr 
    [size] => 300 
)
```

It would be better to combine `parse_str()` with `parse_url()` like so:

```
$url = "somepage?id=123&lang=gr&size=300";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $array );
print_r( $array );
```

Comment: I guess it is expecting `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: how to array to string url
ex. : 
Array ( 
    [somepage?id] => 123 
    [lang] => gr 
    [size] => 300 
)
output = somepage?id=123&lang=gr&size=300

Answer (score 38):

Using [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str).

```
$str = 'pg_id=2&parent_id=2&document&video';
parse_str($str, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Perhaps add something about the deprecation of certain usages of `parse_str`? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 23):

If you're having a problem converting a query string to an array because of encoded ampersands

```
&amp;
```

then be sure to use `html_entity_decode`

Example:

```
// Input string //
$input = 'pg_id=2&amp;parent_id=2&amp;document&amp;video';

// Parse //
parse_str(html_entity_decode($input), $out);

// Output of $out //
array(
  'pg_id' => 2,
  'parent_id' => 2,
  'document' => ,
  'video' =>
)
```

Comment: This was critical to remove the unwanted &amp;

Answer (score 21):

Use https://www.php.net/parse_str

Attention, its usage is:

```
parse_str($str, &$array);
```

not

```
$array = parse_str($str);
```

Please note that the above *only applies to PHP version 5.3 and earlier*. Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in PHP 5.4.

Comment: It's` parse_str($str,$arr);` and not `parse_str($str,&$arr);` terrible mistake

Comment: That is "`&$arr`" vs. "`$arr`" (`&` difference).

Comment: @user8241064: Isn't that just the formal parameters? (Yes, you have left the building, but perhaps somebody else can chime in?)

Comment: @pushrbx: It is not clear what should be used for later versions of PHP (or all versions of PHP). It is as if you are suggesting ***nothing*** applies for later versions of PHP (that is probably not the case or what you meant). Can you clarify? It is probably best in comments here first, before suggesting another edit.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I made my edit with the assumption that the reader  knows what is meant by "call-time pass by reference" and that it has been removed. I meant that the correct syntax would be `parse_str($str, $array);` instead of `parse_str($str, &$array);` in future versions of PHP. Also according to SO guidelines, this bit of info should be there I think.

Answer (score 20):

There are several possible methods, but for you, there is already a built-in [`parse_str` function](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-str.php):

```
$array = array();
parse_str($string, $array);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Perhaps add something about the deprecation of certain usages of `parse_str`? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 6):

This is a one-liner for parsing a query from the current URL into an array:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
<?php
    $str = "pg_id=2&parent_id=2&document&video";
    $array = array();
    parse_str($str, $array);
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [pg_id] => 2
    [parent_id] => 2
    [document] =>
    [video] =>
)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68964806/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP string function `parse_str()` followed by `foreach` loop.

```
$str="pg_id=2&parent_id=2&document&video";
parse_str($str,$my_arr);
foreach($my_arr as $key=>$value){
  echo "$key => $value<br>";
}
print_r($my_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

But PHP already comes with a built in $_GET function. this will convert it to the array by itself.

try `print_r($_GET)` and you will get the same results.

Answer (score -3):

This is the PHP code to split a query in [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server):

```
function splitquery($strquery)
{
    $arrquery = explode('select', $strquery);

    $stry = ''; $strx = '';

    for($i=0; $i<count($arrquery); $i++)
    {
        if($i == 1)
        {
            echo 'select ' . trim($arrquery[$i]);
        }
        elseif($i > 1)
        {
            $strx = trim($arrquery[($i-1)]);

            if(trim(substr($strx,-1)) != '(')
            {
                $stry = $stry . '

                        select ' . trim($arrquery[$i]);
            }
            else
            {
                $stry = $stry.trim('select ' . trim($arrquery[$i]));
            }
            $strx = '';
        }
    }
    return $stry;
}
```

Example:

### Query before

```
Select xx from xx select xx,(select xx) from xx where y='    cc'
select xx from xx left join (select xx) where (select top 1 xxx from xxx) oder by xxx desc";
```

### Query after

```
select xx from xx

select xx,(select xx) from xx where y='    cc'

select xx from xx left join (select xx) where (select top 1 xxx from xxx) oder by xxx desc
```

Answer (score -5):

For this specific question the chosen answer is correct but if there is a redundant parameter—like an extra "e"—in the  URL the function will silently fail without an error or exception being thrown:

```
a=2&b=2&c=5&d=4&e=1&e=2&e=3
```

So I prefer using my own parser like so:

```
//$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = `a=2&b=2&c=5&d=4&e=100&e=200&e=300` 

$url_qry_str  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

//arrays that will hold the values from the url
$a_arr = $b_arr = $c_arr = $d_arr = $e_arr =  array();

foreach( $url_qry_str as $param )
    {
      $var =  explode('=', $param, 2);
      if($var[0]=="a")      $a_arr[]=$var[1];
      if($var[0]=="b")      $b_arr[]=$var[1];
      if($var[0]=="c")      $c_arr[]=$var[1];
      if($var[0]=="d")      $d_arr[]=$var[1];
      if($var[0]=="e")      $e_arr[]=$var[1];
    }

    var_dump($e_arr); 
    // will return :
    //array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "100" [1]=> string(1) "200" [2]=> string(1) "300" }
```

Now you have all the occurrences of each parameter in its own array, you can always merge them into one array if you want to.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You should never have the same query param name with different values. It does not make sense since only one will be accepted anyway.