# Converting a querystring into an associative array

Tags: php, query-string

In PHP, I need a function to convert a querystring from an URL, say: `http://example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2` into a PHP associative array : `array ['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2']`.

I've come up to this piece of code. It works, but I find it a bit lengthy. (And PHP has built-in functions for everything: I'm surprised I haven't found anything out-of-the-box, something like the reverse of `http_build_query`.)

Can you suggest a better way to do this?

```
function getUrlParams($url) {
  $querystring = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
  $a = explode("&", $querystring);
  if (!(count($a) == 1 && $a[0] == "")) {
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
      $b = explode("=", $value);
      $a[$b[0]] = $b[1];
      unset ($a[$key]);
    }
    return $a;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse query string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can get just the atributes from a URL using [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Once you have that you can use [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert them to variables, it works with multidimensional arrays too!

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Comment: `parse_str` ? Function name not explicit at all, but that's it!

Comment: `parse_str` is not always the ideal solution because querystring parameters that contain a dot like `user.name` will be converted to `user_name`, since PHP doesn't support variable names that include a dot

Comment: It just adds the variables to your scope? That seems like an unnecessary security issue

Comment: fucking awesome stuff mate, thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you mean as what you written then it is very simple and don't need anything else there is a predefined Superglobal variable `$_GET` in PHP which itself represents all the query string as key, value pairs associative array.

Example:

```
// current page URI: http://localhost/test.php?key1=value1&key2=value2

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array(
    [key1] = value1
    [key2] = value2
)
```

For more information about `$_GET` PHP superglobal goto: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3';

preg_match_all('/\w+=.*/',$url,$matches);

parse_str($matches[0][0], $output);

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) $arr["$key"]= $value;
```

Comment: When providing code that solves the problem, it is best to also give at least a short explanation of how it works so that folks reading won't have to mentally parse it line by line to understand the differences.

Comment: What does this accomplish that `$arr = $_GET` doesn't?

Answer (score -3):

Try using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: `parse_url` isn't making a array from a querystring. It just parses the URL and returns the different parts as strings.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @pb2q no, this does not answer the question.