# How query string will split or delimit and put those values in array and display them

Tags: php

```js
This is my  script code 

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
     var query = '?';
     var str = $("form").serialize();
     $("#results").text(query += str);
     var x = $("#results").text();
     return x;
 }

 
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){    
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());
    console.log(jsonString);

 $.ajax({
    url: 'insert_value.php',
    data: jsonString,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(function(resp) {
    $('#result').html(resp)
  });
  });  
  </script>
```

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);

$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT value FROM combo1");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
  $array = Array();
  $array1 = Array();
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         //echo "<br> value: ". $row['value'].  "<br>";
          $array[] = $row['value'];

}
print_r($array);
}


$keys = array();
$values = array();
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    $keys[] = $key;
    $values[] = $value;
}
$arrar1 = array_keys($_GET);
$arrar2 = array_values($_GET);
print_r($arrar1);
print_r($arrar2);
?>
```

`?Gender=Female&id=704136006388169`  my query string is like this so I need to split those   and put them in array
  like below :

> arrar1 :Gender ,id
>   arrar2: Female,70413600638816

so how to do this? 
?Gender=Female&id=704136006388169  my query string is like this so I need to split those   and put them in array
  like below :

array1 :Gender ,id
array2: Female,70413600638816

After splitting of this query  I want insert these values into database table

like array1 values as column names and array2 as column values so how  can I do this please help

eg :gender             id
      Female            70413600638816

Comment: array_chunk($_GET,2);

Comment: Isnt the query string part of an url? @ShrutiAkki, if yes you could use get parameters to get the parameters and their values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a querystring into an associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324593/converting-a-querystring-into-an-associative-array)

Comment: @Abhishek ya I'm getting query string from ajax  and javascript but I'm not getting here how to split those values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse query string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

Comment: i think array_key and array_values is work for you . what problem with that ?

Comment: See my answer @ShrutiAkki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First seperate the query strings using `=` and store it in an array, where `queryString` is equal to the query string.

```
// Our two arrays
$firstArray = array();
$secondArray = array();

// Considering $queryString = "?Gender=Female&id=704136006388169&h=0"
$queryString = substr($queryString, 1);
// Now $queryString = "Gender=Female&id=704136006388169&h=0"
$array = explode('&',$queryString);
// Value of $array will be now be ["Gender=Female", "id=704136006388169", "h=0"]
for($i = 0; $i < $array[].length; $i++){ 
    $tempArray = explode('=', $array[i]);
    // Temp array for the first time will be ["Gender","Female"];
    $firstArray[i] = $tempArray[0];
    $secondArray[i] = $tempArray[1];
}
```

If you want more comment pls.

Comment: thanx for your time valuable response

Comment: ^ pls try it and let me know. If it solves the problem please accept this answer to let others know that it is solved. :) @ShrutiAkko

Comment: how to accept here if i tried to it vote it needs some more reputation I'm not getting