# Fastest method to parse URL parameters into variables in PHP

Tags: php, url, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Parse query string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

What's the **fastest method**, to parse a string of URL parameters into an array of accessible variables?

```
$current_param = 'name=Peter&car=Volvo&pizza=Diavola&....';

// Results in a nice array that I can pass:

$result = array (
    'name'  => 'Peter',
    'car'   => 'Volvo',
    'pizza' => 'Diavola'
)
```

I've tested a regular expression, but this takes way too long. My script needs to parse about 10000+ URLs at once sometimes :-(

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#In_software_development) - keep it simple, stupid

Comment: The fastest method is to use `parse_str`. Regular expressions are way too expensive and the algorithm to parse a URL is very simple. That's the fastest way on **one** machine. If you require performance, you can always split the work across many machines but that's both more expensive and tiny bit harder to implement, especially with PHP.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
$current_param = "name=Peter&car=Volvo&pizza=Diavola";
parse_str($current_param, $result);
print_r($result);
```

The above will output

```
Array
(
    [name] => Peter
    [car] => Volvo
    [pizza] => Diavola
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function can do the trick as you expect:

```
<?php
    $str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
    parse_str($str);
    echo $first;  // value
    echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
    echo $arr[1]; // baz

    parse_str($str, $output);
    echo $output['first'];  // value
    echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
    echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
?>
```