# How to explode URL parameter list string into paired [key] => [value] Array?

Tags: php, url, parameters, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse query string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

How can I explode a string such as:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3
```

So that it becomes:

```
Array {
 [a] => 1
 [b] => 2
 [c] => 3
}
```

Using the regular `explode()` function delimited on the `&` will separate the parameters but not in `[key] => [value]` pairs.

Thanks.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643938/php-fastest-method-to-parse-url-params-into-variables. There are tons of these questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use PHP's [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) function.

```
$str = 'a=1&b=2&c=3';
$exploded = array();
parse_str($str, $exploded);
$exploded['a']; // 1
```

I wonder where you get this string from? If it's part of the URL after the question mark (the *query string* of an URL), you can already access it via the superglobal `$_GET` array:

```
# in script requested with http://example.com/script.php?a=1&b=2&c=3
$_GET['a']; // 1
var_dump($_GET); // array(3) { ['a'] => string(1) '1', ['b'] => string(1) '2', ['c'] => string(1) '3' )
```

Comment: Thanks for this perfect answer.  The problem I'm getting with $_GET is that it is returning more parameters than are actually contained in the URL, so I'm getting the actual URL parameter list from $_SERVER['argv'][0] instead, but it comes in the form of a string, not an array.

Comment: @Programmer Could you elaborate? After using `parse_str($_SERVER['argv'],$args)`, `$_GET`  and `$args` should contain the exact same thing.

Comment: @Kristian, there's not much more to elaborate on, the `$_GET` and `parse_str($_SERVER['argv'],$args)` are producing different results. `parse_str($_SERVER['argv'],$args)` actually matches what is in the URL in the browser, while `$_GET` includes additional parameters not contained in the actual URL.

Comment: @Programmer: this should not happen and is very mysterious. Apart from that awkward behavior, there's no problem with additional parameters, simply don't use them in your script …

Comment: @knittl:  it is strange indeed, and I think it may be caused by an API I am accessing.  But I was needing the actual parameters in the URL and `$_GET` wasn't providing them correctly, so I needed an alternative.

Comment: That API is broken then.

Comment: I think It can appears when you use RewriteRule on .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [**`parse_str()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function:

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
$str = "a=1&b=2&c=3"
$array = array();
$elems = explode("&", $str);
foreach($elems as $elem){
    $items = explode("=", $elem);
    $array[$items[0]] = $items[1];
}
```

Comment: Re-inventing the wheel is not always the best solution … especially if the language already provides a well tested function for the problem

Comment: Additional re-inventing the wheel usually means, that you forget something. For example here you forgot `urldecode()`

Comment: @KingCrunch: In all fairness, the OP made no mention of this being for a URL, so the use of `urldecode()` could be incorrect behavior.  Unlikely, but plausible. :-)

Comment: @KingCrunch.  The questioner NEVER said that this was a query string.  You are arbitrarily making assumptions.  You are right, parse_str() would work if your assumptions are correct.  Making assumptions will cost you hours in programming.  What if this was just a string, and urldecode breaks the data.  What if c=%20 sometimes?  Think before judging

Comment: I know, I also didn't made any assumption, that it may be part of an uri, but also the OP never said, that `=` and `&` cannot be part of a key, or value, thus you must take care of it. You can replace `urldecode()` with every function you like, that is able to escape special characters the way its required (even if it is stupid to confuse others with "unexpected behaviour": When it looks like a query string, it should behave like one). The point is, that there are functions out there, that already can do all this.