# Key value in PHP from URL

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to explode URL parameter list string into paired [key] => [value] Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046279/how-to-explode-url-parameter-list-string-into-paired-key-value-array)

Quick question

I have a URL sting that I wish to output the Key value as an array  eg

$url  ="www.domain.com?test=1&test2=2&test3=3";

and wish to have the output as an array

key => value so I can call any of the keys

eg

```
array (
    test => 1,
    test1 => 2,
    test2 => 3,
)
```

cant use explode & 
Just thinking  do i have to do a loop and match between &  and = for the key

Comment: Looks like this was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046279/how-to-explode-url-parameter-list-string-into-paired-key-value-array

Comment: It seems you're looking for `$_GET`.

Comment: You already have it available with `$_GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
$url = parse_url('www.domain.com?test=1&test2=2&test3=3');
parse_str($url['query'], $keyvalue);

var_dump($keyvalue);
```

`$keyvalue` should contain your desired array.