# Retrieve JSON content from URL

Tags: php, json, jsonp

i have a url which pass JSON content like this

```
script.php?agent={__AGENT_NUMBER__}&type={__CALL_TYPE__}&callerid={__CALL_ID__}&channel={__REMOTE_CHANNEL__}
```

how can i retrieve the content of agent,type,etc in php ?

i got the code from this page: http://juanelojga.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/usando-external-urls-del-modulo-de.html.
This url is to get parameters from a call center

Comment: Um... that's not [JSON](http://www.json.org/) at all... These are [`$REQUEST` parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse query string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

Comment: these are simple GET variables, not JSON ... you get it just like you get any other GET or POST variable, then juste remove the curly brackets if there are...

Comment: i got the code from this page: http://juanelojga.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/usando-external-urls-del-modulo-de.html

Comment: Do you have the url as a string or do you get a request to this url?

Comment: i get a request to this url. is it uses JSONP?

Comment: this url is to get parameters from a call center

Answer (score 1):

a simple $_GET['agent'] should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple just use the `$_GET` method to Retrieve contents

```
<?php echo $_GET['agent']?>
<?php echo $_GET['type']?>
<?php echo $_GET['callerid']?>
```