# Parse string into array of key=>value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a string like:

```
$string = "/key/value/anotherKey/anotherValue/thirdKey/thirdValue"
```

I would like to parse this string to an array of key => value:

```
array(
    key => value,
    anotherKey => anotherValue,
    thirdKey => thirdValue
);
```

The only solution I have found is the following, but it seems that there should be an easier way to achieve my goal:

```
$split = preg_split("[/]", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$i = 0;
$j = 1;
$array = [];
for(;$i<count($split)-1;){
    $array[$split[$i]] = $split[$j];
    $i += 2;
    $j += 2;
}
```

I have looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array), put it only works for query strings like:

```
"key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue&thirdKey=thirdValue"
```

Can anyone guide me towards a more "simple" solution (by that I mean less code to write, the usage of PHP functions and I would like to prevent using loops)? Thank you!

Comment: You could reveiew the Zend 1 source and see how they achieve this with [Zend_Uri](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.uri.chapter.html)

Comment: @skirato i have answered for your question,plz look at that once and let me know.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I like your answer's logic, but it is not working (see comment on answer)

Comment: Downvoter, please explain yourself? How can my question be more clear, explained?

Comment: I have updated my question, please reconsider your downvote :)

Comment: @skirato Too late to party here but I have updated my answer anyway as per your updated question. It does not use loop now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First I [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string into an array. Here I make sure to remove slashes at the beginning and at the end of the string with [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), so I don't get empty elements.

After this I just [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) all elements out which have an even key as keys and all elements with  an odd key as values.

At then end I simply [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) the two arrays into one.

```
<?php

    $string = "/key/value/anotherKey/anotherValue/thirdKey/thirdValue";
    $arr = explode("/", trim($string, "/"));

    $keys = array_filter($arr, function($k){
        return ($k % 2 == 0);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    $values = array_filter($arr, function($k){
        return ($k % 2 == 1);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    $result = array_combine($keys, $values);
    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [key] => value
    [anotherKey] => anotherValue
    [thirdKey] => thirdValue
)
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://3v4l.org/P0Ks4)

For PHP <5.6, just use a workaround with `array_flip()`, since you can't use the flags from `array_filter()`:

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://3v4l.org/AA3F8)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I like this logic, but $keys and $values are null for me...

Comment: @skirato What is the output of: `echo phpversion();` for you?

Comment: @skirato Then the problem is, that you can't use the constants from `array_filter()`, just do a little workaround with `array_flip()` -> http://3v4l.org/AA3F8

Comment: Nice, only thing you should have minimum PHP 5.6.0 for 3rd argument  `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another simply way of achieving this using preg_replace() and parse_str():

```
$string = '/key/value/anotherKey/anotherValue/thirdKey/thirdValue';

// Transform to the query string (replace '/key/val' by 'key=val&')
$string = trim(preg_replace('|/([^/]+)/([^/]+)|', '$1=$2&', $string), '&');

// Parse the query string into array variable
parse_str($string, $new_array);
print_r($new_array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [key] => value
    [anotherKey] => anotherValue
    [thirdKey] => thirdValue
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`explode` it and generate the array by looping through it. Hope this could help -

```
$string = "/key/value/anotherKey/anotherValue/thirdKey/thirdValue";

$vars = explode('/', $string);

$i = 0;
$newArray = array();
while ($i < count($vars)) {
   if (!empty($vars[$i])) {
     $newArray[$vars[$i]] = $vars[$i+1];
     $i += 2;
   } else {
     $i++;
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
  ["anotherKey"]=>
  string(12) "anotherValue"
  ["thirdKey"]=>
  string(10) "thirdValue"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only simplification I see is the fact that you use only one index variable instead of two, which is indeed better. But explode doesn't allow to remove empty values, so you have to use an if/else. For that, I do prefer my preg_split with the NO_EMPTY flag.
I was wondering if there wasn't a way to simplify this much more (but maybe there isn't...)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php

 $string = "/key/value/anotherKey/anotherValue/thirdKey/thirdValue";

 $array  = array_flip(explode('/',rtrim(ltrim($string,'/'),'/')));

 print_r( 
          array_combine(
                        array_flip(array_filter($array,function($v){return (!($v & 1)); })),
                        array_flip(array_filter($array,function($v){return ($v & 1);    })) 
                       )
        );

 ?>
```

**Output**

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 Array
 (
     [key] => value
     [anotherKey] => anotherValue
     [thirdKey] => thirdValue
 )
```

Comment: `rtrim(ltrim($string,'/'),'/')` = `trim($string,' /')`

Answer (score 1):

This is working like as your requirement:
Look at this code once:

```
<?php
$str = 'key/value/anotherKey/anotherValue/thirdKey/thirdValue';
$list = explode('/', $str);
$result = array();
for ($i=0 ; $i<count($list) ; $i+=2) {
    $result[ $list[$i] ] = $list[$i+1];
}
echo "After Split String".'<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
After Split String
Array
(
    [key] => value
    [anotherKey] => anotherValue
    [thirdKey] => thirdValue
)
```

For your reference click [Demo Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/e6lxdZ)