# I want to extract the number by key from a query string.

Tags: php

This is the value i get from db.

```
pkid=1&ordernumber=54322&ordervalue=12345&response=2&scheduleId=1
```

Want to extract response from this.That is `2`.

Comment: what you have tried?? Try something on your own.

Comment: Heres a hint [parse_str()](https://php.net/parse_str).

Comment: This looks like a string of GET Parameters. Why would you get that from your database?

Comment: Have you even tried to search a bit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array

Comment: Thanks  sitilge Ulver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is

```
$str ='pkid=1&ordernumber=54322&ordervalue=12345&response=2&scheduleId=1';
parse_str($str);
echo $response; // output :- 2
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because 1. This doesn't work correctly (You have to echo `$str['response']`, not `$resposne`). 2. The op didn't try anything himself and just wants a solution. Giving them an answer makes you look like a repwh ... well, someone who just wants reputation. People don't like that.

Comment: Alright nvm, that works, forgot that parse_str() creates variables too ._.

Comment: @YUNOWORK your point 2 is not correct at all. If same question would answer who have 100K reputation, you guys give up vote.  Reputation  really matters. Anyway thanks for the advice

Comment: @YUNOWORK- I tried to find a solution on stackoverflow but i got nothing.i was searching by the same headline "I want to extract the number by key from a query string".