# PHP get all substrings between each occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: php, arrays, substring, delimiter

I have a set of query strings stored in a database as so

```
&foo=bar&foo2=bar2
```

How would I successfully iterate through this string to extract each key and value into an array using the keys as the array keys too?

Had a look around and other questions on here seem to only be for one value.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
<?php
$string = "&foo=bar&foo2=bar2";
parse_str($string, $output);
print_r($output);
```

See it here https://eval.in/484197

Answer (score 0):

```
function string2KeyedArray($string, $delimiter = '&', $kv = '=') {
  if ($a = explode($delimiter, $string)) { // create parts
foreach ($a as $s) { // each part
  if ($s) {
    if ($pos = strpos($s, $kv)) { // key/value delimiter
      $ka[trim(substr($s, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($s, $pos + strlen($kv)));
    } else { // key delimiter not found
      $ka[] = trim($s);
    }
  }
}
return $ka;
  }
}
```

Now you can use

```
$string = "&foo=bar&foo2=bar2";
print_r(string2KeyedArray($string));

//Output: Array ( [foo] => bar [foo2] => bar2 )
```