# php printing a text variable from a curl function

Tags: php, curl, printing

I have a curl function which outputs the following text from an api.
`number=1&id=731&name=test&value=6311`

How could I make a variable which will store one of these values in the text such as I want to make a variable called `$name` which will have the 'test' value from the output of the api. I saw different things such as in json you can use `$variable['name']` but it doesn't seem to work like this.. help

Comment: Show the code you've tried - your php code and your curl command and sample of what gets returned

Comment: `parse_str('number=1&id=731&name=test&value=6311'); echo $name; // test`

Comment: Or so `parse_str('number=1&id=731&name=test&value=6311', $variable); echo $variable['name'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

[Parse query string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

Use parse_str function, it looks like:

```
 $get_string = "number=1&id=731&name=test&value=6311";

 parse_str($get_string, $get_array);

 print_r($get_array);
```