# How to substring within the special character using PHP?

Tags: php, substr

I need to sub-string the value within some special character using PHP. I am showing the original string below.

```
"name=G%20+%20l&cid=20"
```

In the above string I need the value within `name=` to next `&`.

Comment: If this is coming from the request URL, then `$_GET['name']`

Comment: No,My general string is like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse query string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

Comment: If it isn't your url, then look at using PHP's built-in [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function; a lot better than using explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$string = "name=G%20+%20l&cid=20";
$explode_string = explode("&", $string);

$explode_string2 = explode("name=", $explode_string[0]);
echo array_pop($explode_string2);
```

Output will be like:

```
G%20+%20l
```

Comment: Output should be like  `G%20+%20l`.