# how to get POST parameters from URL in PHP

Tags: php, post, woocommerce, get, request

I have this POST request:
http://localhost/wordpress/muj-ucet/?OPERATION=CREATE_ORDER&ORDERNUMBER=2725&MERORDERNUM=84&PRCODE=0&SRCODE=0&RESULTTEXT=OK&DIGEST=K%2BfIxT6L2oww32%2FmkofsewQV7y%2B%2FpPySi5XTabu%2FQVGAWi01hnuYRmvXfNvzn2ykroExAL61YvwxpVTQXaicfzuDPpr0mcuELMRzG2pH4dbnFFUnZ9ztnMrnFXtGmf48rc4i3r1O3A2MrDoRCMZ7OqpQt2zAgPGZSVTto%2FoNYlJRuOkhZzTwi%2BOC9RWVLGSUN81t%2FVAgUnrwQDEKKIfgPomC5BsSQlHYfBATvVltD3L0DO1eVeUNxcvh9xBHJ%2BxZZT%2Bbd8z3%2BtJwn6vnS2r5u%2BNunUsGFYJZpK7BbjSjCTsxO2SKib%2B%2FoKWLmU7yaZWYawcAGQzu0jbpcVd0SrxUcw%3D%3D&DIGEST1=EnmOfGWjP5ly3OacV0sUhS6l59oLVDLwprpEb5Pg%2FporFM3fgjMzCHaZF1hKq3SUQ7%2BZO2UmyjQnSQ8%2Bk9dtQaSduunpja7wtDlOx%2BItFtFxF7rWyYpE6X%2FQkTIxoLRs7KjcIBRB2U34do9xrFyoNQvUWuxDMAaZ2yuu80SYxnx5qPY80wlDWlS2MFyEXvhO%2BCuz2v8NorPKcm7xLvLt%2F0PPYgB%2FeFuLMsDIGPGo6TMJtdU0NRSF4dkQAKouchILiUZvhyN80ou2%2B3bSWnPNfmcK5gWZQoGKl1qENMe87zsTa71TdxZR4AnlEzxWXhYwVFRh%2B8LueKNNM6%2FRtXVhLQ%3D%3D
And I would like to take these parameters from URL And get them into this code:

```
public function responseOrder(){
    $response = new WebPayResponse ();
    $response->setPublicKey (__DIR__."/key/".$this->get_option("public_key"));
    $response->setResponseParams ($_GET);
    $result = $response->verify();
    echo 'FUNGUJ KURVA';
    if ($result){
        echo 'Payment successful';
           empty_cart();
    }else
            echo 'Payment failed';
}
```

Comment: If it is in the URL it isn't POST parameters

Comment: So what is your problem? Does this work? If not, *how* doesn't it work? What you expect? What do you get? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us what you tried, what fails and maybe an error log or something. You can also check the "How to ask" guidelines of StackOverflow.

Comment: Lukas, what you're looking for is probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array
and this issue is possible duplicate of it