# Replace certain part of a string

Tags: php, string, replace

How can I replace a certain part of a string. For example we have the URL:

```
username=[LINK]&quantity=10&limit=[POSTS]&interval=5&url=https://google.com/&service=762&runs=[RUNS]&type=Comments
```

I want to keep the parameters, quantity=*\, limit=*, interval=* & runs=*.

I've tried to do it with parsing but can't get it work,

```
 parse_str($p_api, $query);                                   
 $quantity = '&quantity='.$query['quantity'];
 $limit = '&limit='.$query['limit'];
 $interval = '&interval='.$query['interval'];
 $runs = '&runs='.$query['runs'];
```

How can I update all other data but keep these parameters as they are in the default string?

Comment: What does `quantity=\, limit=, interval=* & runs=*` mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse query string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array)

Comment: They are just variables, for example: quantity=15, interval=5... the point is to keep their values but everything else to be changed.

Comment: `"can't get parse_str to work`" do you see any error messages or do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: No, i mean the logic with parse_str i can't get it to work because i am not sure how can i replace only certain parts of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse query  `parse_str()`, update array value you wish and `http_build_query()` for url encoding

```
$str = "username=[LINK]&quantity=10&limit=[POSTS]&interval=5&url=https://google.com/&service=762&runs=[RUNS]&type=Comments";
  parse_str($str,$query);
  $query['username']  = "xyz";
  $query['type'] = "post";
  echo http_build_query($query);
```

[Demo](http://tpcg.io/GIEqs5)