# parse_str() need someting on PHP 7

Tags: php

I have updated [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) server and now my PHP version is PHP 7.2.1. After the update, I get the error

> Deprecated: parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result
> argument is deprecated in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/functions/checklogin.php on line 3

from this code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
        parse_str($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uid='$u' AND username='$u_name'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == '0'){
            header("Location: " . $base_url . "logout.php");
        }
    }
    else{
      header("Location: " . $base_url . "logout.php");
    }
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the [PHP documentation says](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php):

> Without the second argument to parse_str(), the query string parameters would populate the local symbol table. Given the security implications of this, using parse_str() without a second argument has now been deprecated. The function should always be used with two arguments, as the second argument causes the query string to be parsed into an array.

You can write `parse_str($_COOKIE[$cookie_name], $myArray);` instead of `parse_str($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);` to resolve this problem

And use `extract($myArray);` just after this line;

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        parse_str($_COOKIE[$cookie_name], $myArray);
        extract($myArray);
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uid='$u' AND username='$u_name'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == '0') {
            header("Location: " . $base_url . "logout.php");
        }
    }
    else {
      header("Location: " . $base_url . "logout.php");
    }
?>
```

Also, you should use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to secure your site.

Comment: @robit-rasela Thank you for your answer. If you have a time can you check my other question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791258/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-post-updatespost-viewcount-in?noredirect=1#comment94433807_53791258