# how to get UTM to text on page from a URL which is result of a filter?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, filter, utm

I am using a plugin (directories). If I filter directories I get something like this

```
/?filter_field_age%5B%5D=35&filter_field_regions%5B%5D=America
```

I want to get "35" and "America" to appear on page as text.

I used

```
function UTMParam( $atts ) {  
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'param' => 'param',
    ), $atts ) );
    return $_GET[$param];  
}
add_shortcode('UTMParam', 'UTMParam');
```

and

```
[UTMParam param='filter_field_age'] [UTMParam param='filter_field_regions']
```

But its not working....any idea????

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397726/parse-query-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), but you'll have to strip the `/?` first :

```
$str = '/?filter_field_age%5B%5D=35&filter_field_regions%5B%5D=America';
$query = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Result :

```
[
  'filter_field_age' => [
      0 => '35',
  ],
  'filter_field_regions' => [
      0 => 'America',
  ],
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. BUT as I am not good in php. I tried what you suggested but it did not work. Let me clarify.... the query filter_field_age%5B%5D=35&filter_field_regions%5B%5D=America' is a result of filter, so every time a user changes filter the results also changes.

Comment: So your issue is getting `$str`, or updating the result? Unless it's a wordpress specific issue...

Comment: my goal is to show the $str (whatever filtered result is in url after "filter_field_age%5B%5D")....to a text on page or form field using short code..and yes its a wordpress site