# What does the value attribute mean for checkboxes in HTML?

Tags: html

Suppose this checkbox snippet:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">Is it worth?</input>
```

Is there any reason to statically define the `value` attribute of checkboxes in HTML? What does it mean?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_value.asp W3Schools has wonderful information about checkboxes.

Comment: empty params are OK by the URI standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value but I think that forms ignore inputs without value (even though it is useless when you don't have multiple checkboxes grouped by a single `name`), even though it is valid HTML to omit `value`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I hope I understand your question right.

The value attribute defines a value which is sent by a POST request (i.e. You have an HTML form submitted to a server). 
Now the server gets the name (if defined) and the value.

```
<form method="post" action="urlofserver">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="1">Is it worth?</input>
</form>
```

The server would receive `mycheckbox` with the value of `1`.

in PHP, this POST variable is stored in an array as `$_POST['mycheckbox']` which contains `1`.

Comment: I think the questioner was asking why the checkbox has a value; rather than a checked state.

Comment: So do we need to set both `value` and `checked` attributes like `<input name="is_active" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value={{ $user->is_active }} checked={{ $user->is_active }}>` ?

Comment: The OP is gone, but this answer ought to be updated with information about the default value if the "value" attribute is left out (or if the "value" attribute is required, what happens then (could be browser/version dependent)). Also, what is the recommended value (convention)? [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323899/what-does-the-value-attribute-mean-for-checkboxes-in-html/38914478#38914478) here claims the default value is "on".

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to make a comment on Adriano Silva's comment. 
In order to get what he describes to work you have to add "[]" at the end of the name attribute, so if we take his example the correct syntax should be:

```
<input type = "checkbox" name="BrandID[]" value="1">Ford</input>
<input type = "checkbox" name="BrandID[]" value="2">GM</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="BrandId[]" value="3">Volkswagen</input>
```

Then you use something like: $test = $_POST['BrandID']; (Mind no need for [] after BrandID in the php code).
Which will give you an array of values, the values in the array are the checkboxes that are ticked's values.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Your example is specific to PHP, [I explain this in a comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14324382/175071), just wanted to add that :)

Comment: `select multiple` may be a better choice in this case.

Answer (score 7):

One reason is to use the ease of working with values ​​in the system.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="BrandId" value="1">Ford</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="BrandId" value="2">GM</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="BrandId" value="3">Volkswagen</input>
```

Comment: And what this means? If someone checks Ford and GM, for example, what happens?

Comment: On the server side you get an array with the name BrandId with selected values (E.g 1,2)

Comment: @Metalcoder keep in mind, PHP will put the values into an array under the key "BrandId", thus if you check all them you will end up with `array('BrandId'=>'3')` while in reality the browser sent this: `BrandId=1&BrandId=2&BrandId=3`

Comment: @TimoHuovinen yes, the name should be BrandId[] in order to get all values, right?

Comment: @Metalcoder only if you use the `$_POST` variable, but you don't need the square brackets if you use `$post_str=file_get_contents("php://input");` for example. (There is also `php://stdin` btw)

Comment: What is this for? For checkboxes to work like radio buttons?

Answer (score 4):

When the form is submitted, the data in the `value` attribute is used as the value of the form input if the checkbox is checked. The default value is "on".

```js
$('form').on('change', update).trigger('change')

function update() {
  var form = $(this)
  form.find('output').text('→ ' + form.serialize())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo">
  <output></output>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" checked>
  <output></output>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1" checked>
  <output></output>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bananas" checked>
  <output></output>
</form>
```

Comment: Re *'The default value is "on"'*: Do you have a source for that (claim)?

Comment: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-value "If the value is not otherwise specified, it is the string `on` by default."

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#sec-constructing-the-form-data-set "If the field element has a value attribute specified, then let value be the value of that attribute; otherwise, let value be the string "on"."

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of a quick glance answer, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-value)

> when a form is submitted, only checkboxes which are currently checked are submitted to the server, and the reported value is the value of the value attribute

It can be confusing because seeing something like
`<input type='checkbox' name='activated' value='1'>` might lead one to believe that the 1 means true and it will be treated as though it is checked, which is false. The `checked` attribute itself also only determines if the checkbox should be checked by default on page load, *not* whether it is currently checked and thus going to be submitted.