# Is passing a query string parameter (whose value is null) without the equals sign valid?

Tags: http, url, query-string

Variation 1:

```
 file.jsp?parameter1=&parameter2=abc
```

Variation 2:

```
 file.jsp?parameter1&parameter2=abc
```

I know Variation 1 is considered valid, but is variation 2 considered valid?  Specifically, there is no value for the parameter, is the equals sign required in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a url query parameter valid if it has no value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is valid to have query parameter with just the parameter name.

If you are familiar with Java,  Look at the @see [UriComponentsBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) QueryParam function, by default it does this for any query parameter with null.

> If no values are given, the resulting URI will contain the query
>   parameter name only (i.e. ?foo instead of ?foo=bar.

See this answer for more info.
[Is a url query parameter valid if it has no value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value)