# Is a URL query parameter valid if it has no value with equal symbol?

Tags: url, query-string

This is really similar to this question : [Is a url query parameter valid if it has no value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value)

However what if I still use the symbol `=` like:

```
http://example.com/foo?bar=&pam=e
```

Reason is that I use built-in function to generate URL, and when I set `bar` to nothing, it does this in shown format.

Comment: This question is more accurately a duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291562/is-passing-a-query-string-parameter-whose-value-is-null-without-the-equals-sig

Comment: As the accepted answer to the linked question says: "The URI RFC doesn't mandate a format for the query string. Although it is recognized that the query string will often carry name-value pairs, it is not required to." So there is no rule to break, and the query string is valid, with or without equal sign.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a url query parameter valid if it has no value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value)

Comment: @m69 the link you mentionned above was asking for a param without the "=" symbol. Thanks for your answer! Now I know my implementation is gonna be fine!!