# AngularJS $resource query parameter with no value

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource

From the AngularJS 1.6.x [`$resource` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) I know that I can pass in query name/value parameters using a JavaScript object. For example `{foo: "bar"}` for the path `path/example` will access a RESTful URL using something like `path/example?foo=bar`.

But what if I want to pass a query parameter with no value, e.g. `path/example?foo`? Do I use `{foo: ""}` or `{foo: null}` or some other form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What can be easier than just trying foo:"", foo: null, and see what happens?

Comment: Related: [Is a url query parameter valid if it has no value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value).

Answer (score 0):

you should just be able to omit the query parameter. This is an example of a query that could return all users:

```
let User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId: '@id'});
User.query().$promise.then(function(users) {
  allUsers = users;
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#basic-usage