# Cross-domain linker plugin decorates links, but browser navigates to un-decorated url

Tags: browser, google-analytics, cross-domain, gtag.js

I am using the gtag.js linker plugin, and its autoLink feature. When I turn GA debugging on, I see in the console:

```
Link decorated: https://mysedanweb.limosys.com/JlimoWeb/?y=&_insput=3147729489-1348501718&_ga=2.163929663.1298871253.1551969782-111678887.1551969782
Navigated to https://mysedanweb.limosys.com/JlimoWeb/?y
```

So in other words, the link decoration is working, and appears to happen prior to the browser navigating to the next page, but it navigates to the url without the additional parameters. So, cross-domain tracking doesn't work.

Has anyone seen this problem? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a malformed URL.

```
https://mysedanweb.limosys.com/JlimoWeb/?y=**SOMETHING**&_insput=3147729489-1348501718&_ga=2.163929663.1298871253.1551969782-111678887.1551969782
```

You need to specify a value for `y` .

Comment: No, I don't think there is anything requiring url parameters to have values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not know that. Either way your website was upset about it for some reason. I tried also moving y at the end and this way, it works. https://mysedanweb.limosys.com/JlimoWeb/?_insput=3147729489-1348501718&_ga=2.163929663.1298871253.1551969782-111678887.1551969782&y

Comment: What I discovered is that for new sessions (no cookies set by either domain) there is a server-side redirect happening that is removing all the x-domain linker parameters. Perhaps also the redirect only matches with the ?y there...I haven't tested that.