# Pass query params to Axios with no value

Tags: axios

Can the `params` object of an Axios config of a get request accept a [query parameter with no value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value), to construct a URL such as `http://example.com/foo?a=true&b`? Perhaps something like:

```js
const val = true
axios.get('/api/my_page/', {
    params: {
        a: val,
        b // although JavaScript interprets this as `b: b`
    }
})
```

Or is my only option to put the query parameters directly in the URL, with something like:

```js
axios.get(`/api/my_page/?a=${val}&b`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no purpose of having the variable `b` being passed, I'll suggest skipping it altogether. Else you can follow of the below ways

```js
params: {
    a: val,
    b: null
}
```

This will give you the query params as `/api/my_page/?a=hello`

or you can use the one below

```js
params: {
    a: val,
    b: ''
}
```

This will give you the query params as `/api/my_page/?a=hello&b=`

I don't think it's really possible to get `b` alone. You either get `b=` or nothing, unless you explicitly hard-code it as you've shown in the one below

```js
axios.get(`/api/my_page/?a=${val}&b`)
```

But this will be identical to `b=` in behaviour.

Also, when using the object

```js
params: {
    a: val,
    b
}
```

it might throw an error. At least it does on JsFiddle React 0.14.3