# Problem consuming api rest with camel-http4

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-http

I'm trying to consume the following url:

```java
.to("https4://www.example.com/demo?execute&bridgeEndpoint=true")
```

but apparently the request comes out like this:

```java
.to("https4://www.example.com/demo?execute=&bridgeEndpoint=true")
```

Which makes me not give anything back, does anyone know it could be? The correct url is without (=)

Comment: The query URL is wrong and Camel is looking like it's trying to do the right thing.  Just having `execute` as a query without an equals expression is not compliant with [the existing standards](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3).

Comment: The [URI RFC does not mandate a format for the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557387/is-a-url-query-parameter-valid-if-it-has-no-value).

Comment: since a postman type client responds correctly, there will be some configuration that I can make in camel so that I do not add that (=) to the end of the url?