# Does the python requests library support query param with no value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a server side API with the following URL

```
https://example.com/abc/JSONInterface.jsp?param1=param1_val&param2=param2_val&param3
```

If you notice the param3 it has no value nor is it null/None

As per this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4557490/3564468) such URLs are acceptable.

Is it possible to call such an api with python requests library?
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/

If not is there another library that can handle this?

Comment: requests accepts a dictionary as a param input - https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

If I create a param with None value the library skips the param.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to send a string as the `params` parameter

```
data = {'param1': 'param1',
        'param2': 'param2',
        'param3': None}

params = '&'.join([k if v is None else f"{k}={v}" for k, v in data.items()])
response = requests.get('https://example.com/abc/JSONInterface.jsp', params=params)
```

Comment: Thanks. At this point I think thats the only way. Was just wondering if there was library support directly